# Embedding Twitter Timeline - Links to open in a new page

Tags: html, twitter

Is it possible to get the embedded timeline to open links in a new page?

This is what I got from twitter to copy and paste into my page and it works great, but I would like it to open links in a new page, not the same page.

```
<a class="twitter-timeline" href="https://twitter.com/GraftonMedical" data-widget-id="414828595198951424">Tweets by @GraftonMedical</a>
<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+"://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to open link in a new page just add to "a" tag:

```
target="_blank"
```

...if you meant on that.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work on the links that show in individual tweets

Comment: I think it might rather be something that would have to be changed in the javascript?

Comment: You can do that in js:
http://jsfiddle.net/hGdJ9/
That will open every link in new tab...you can change part $('a').